# details about the question between strong/weaker topologies and compact/Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

I've just learned a corollary says

> A continuous bijective map from a compact space onto a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism.

Then I want to prove that for a compact Hausdorff topology $\omega$ on a set $X$, if $\omega_0$ is strictly stronger (weaker) than $\omega$, than is must be Hausdorff (compact) but not compact (Hausdorff).

It's obvious to see if $\omega_0$ is weaker then it is Hausdorff, since a compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed. But I feel a bit confused to show $\omega_0$ is stronger than it is Hausdorff.

And according to Edoardo Lanari's answer, suppose $(X, \tau)$ is the topological space from which we start, if $\sigma$ is a weaker topology on $X$ and $(X,\tau)$ is compact-Hausdorff, then why the map $Id: (X,\tau) \rightarrow (X,\sigma)$ is a continuous bijection?  (I mean, since $\sigma$ should be strictly weaker, so the map won't be one-one. )

May be a silly question, I'm just a newbie, can any one help me figure it out?

Edoardo Lanari, Weaker/Stronger Topologies and Compact/Hausdorff Spaces, URL (version: 2013-05-12): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/389576

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $(X,\tau)$ and $(X,\sigma)$ are such that $\sigma \subseteq \tau$ ($\sigma$ is weaker than $\tau$) then $\textrm{id}: (X, \tau) \to (X,\sigma)$ is continuous because a function is continuous iff every inverse image of an open set is open:

$$\forall O \in \sigma: \textrm{id}^{-1}[O]=O \in \tau \text{ as } \sigma \subseteq \tau$$

The function $\textrm{id}$ as a function from $X$ to $X$ is always a bijection (regardless of topologies on either side); this is just a set theory fact and has nothing to do with weaker/stronger topologies.

So if $(X,\tau)$ is compact and $\sigma \subseteq \tau$ is Hausdorff, then $\textrm{id}$ is continuous as I already explained and a bijection and so your very first theorem concludes from compactness of $\tau$ and Hausdorffness of $\sigma$ that $\textrm{id}: (X,\tau) \to (X, \sigma)$ is a homeomorphism. In particular it is an open map, so

$$\forall O \in \tau: \textrm{id}[O]=O \in \sigma \text{ or otherwise put: } \tau \subseteq \sigma$$

So in conclusion:

> Let $(X,\tau)$ be compact Hausdorff and suppose $\sigma$ is a weaker topology than $\tau$ on $X$. Then if $\sigma$ is **properly** weaker, then $(X,\sigma)$ is not Hausdorff.

Similarly:

> Let $(X,\tau)$ be compact Hausdorff and suppose $\sigma$ is a stronger topology than $\tau$ on $X$. Then if $\sigma$ is **properly** stronger, then $(X,\sigma)$ is not compact.

Proof of the latter is similar: $\textrm{id}: (X,\sigma) \to (X, \tau)$ is continuous as $\tau \subseteq \sigma$; we assumed the domain is compact and we know the codomain is Hausdorff so again we conclude *this* $\textrm{id}$ is also open and so $\sigma \subseteq \tau$ hence $\sigma=\tau$ contradicting *properly** stronger. So the assumption that $(X,\sigma)$ is compact must be false.

Comment: For the latter one, why the codomain is Hausdorff?

Comment: @KoseungZayong $(X,\tau)$ is Hausdorff isn’t it?

Comment: I got it. I’ve made a mistake.  I want ask one more question. A topology is Hausdorff, then whether the stronger one will also be Hausdorff.

Comment: @KoseungZayong of course, that’s obvious. The needed sets to separate are already in the weaker topology, so also in the stronger one. The more open sets, the easier it is to be Hausdorff and the harder it is to be compact ( more open covers).